# Simplest way to create a java.sql.Date for December 31, 9999 (UTC)?

Tags: java, date

I would like to create a java.sql.Date for December 31, 9999 (UTC). Currently I'm using this:

```
Date eot = new Date(new GregorianCalendar(9999, Calendar.DECEMBER, 31).getTimeInMillis());
```

However, it strikes me as ugly. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: `Date`s are always ugly.

Comment: ...why do you want a `java.sql.Date`?  Why can't you just use `java.time.LocalDate`?  As near as I'm aware, most (all?) of the major JPA providers support the `java.time` types by now.

Comment: In addition to @Clockwork-Muse comment, I won't be surprised if `java.sql.Date` will be deprecated in the near future.

Comment: @shmosel `Date.from` returns a `java.util.Date` not a `java.sql.Date`.  Also those intermediate values are really constants and should be declared as such. `java.util/sql.Dates` are mutable so they should not be constants.

Comment: @Jeff I missed that. Posted an answer for `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: @shmosel examined the valueOf logic it's very costly. Restoring my answer.

Comment: @shmosel further he wanted it in UTC, don't think `valueof` does that.

Comment: @Jeff `java.sql.Date` represents a date without a time or zone.

Comment: @shmosel the user wants the value in UTC.  The value of the `time` field in the `Date` object should be `253402214400000L`, the time in millis in UTC.  The `valueOf` method generates (very slowly) a time in millis based on the system time zone.

Comment: @Jeff The time field is an implementation detail that any proper database driver will ignore. See the documentation of [`setDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-). Also note that OP's example isn't doing any time zone conversion.

Comment: @shmosel I am aware that the OP's code is wrong and of how the spec behaves, but we don't have any further information about the intended use of the `j.s.Dates` that the OP intends to generate I believe the safest course of action is to provide an answer that would create `j.s.Dates` that have the correct value for UTC start of day on 9999-12-31.

Comment: @Jeff You may be right, but I'm inclined to believe OP's code is correct and his request is inaccurate.

Comment: @shmosel Could be!

Comment: @Jeff I'm inclined to think both my code is correct and my request accurate! Please note that the GregorianCalendar getTime method returns the time in UTC.

Comment: @ktm5124 Not as a rule.

Comment: @shmosel The documentation says as much. How can you say it's not a rule?

Comment: It returns the time as UTC milliseconds, but when you convert it to `Date`, that timestamp is interpreted using the default time zone.

Comment: How can a date like December 31, 9999 be or not be in UTC?

Comment: I still suggest that you don’t want a `java.sql.Date`. If this is for an SQL datrabase, your JDBC 4.2 driver will be happy to accept a `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just use a constant?

```
Date eot = new Date(253402214400000L);
```

Also note, the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) say that `8099-12-31` is the latest date supported.  That would be `193444070400000L`.  Though in testing, it seems to work with `9999-12-31` just fine.

Also, I'll just point out you should probably avoid this API and use the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) APIs instead.

Comment: That is what my answer does and avoids magic numbers.Well aside from `9999`.

Comment: Great answer! Using a constant is indeed simpler and more elegant. I'm using java.sql.Date and not java.time for two reasons: (1) I want to persist the date in Spring JdbcTemplate and (2) our company is using Java 5 or Java 6 and I'm not sure if java.time is supported in those versions.

Comment: @shmosel His answer uses the exact same logic as mine, except that he plugs in a constant whereas I get that constant as the return value of a function call.

Comment: @ktm5124 That constant only produces your date in certain time zones. If you run this on Pacific Time, for example, it'll result in 12/30/9999.

Comment: @shmosel Right, but I'm only interested in UTC, so it's all good, is it not? Besides, the GregorianCalendar getTime method produces the time in UTC, so it's using the same logic as my original method.

Comment: @ktm5124 Your `GregorianCalendar` will produce the expected date in the default time zone, not necessarily UTC. I don't know what you mean by "interested in UTC". If your default time zone is UTC, this solution should work. But it's not very portable. Unless you use the [`setDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-java.util.Calendar-) overload that accepts a time zone.

Comment: @ktm5124 note that my answer also uses a constant but avoids magic numbers.

Comment: @shmosel - The object itself takes input in terms of UTC, so it doesn't matter what the system time zone is for the purpose of construction.  The local time zone does matter, but it comes into play when emitting as a string (via .toString(), etc.)).  This duality is one of the many problems with both `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date` that is resolved with java.time APIs like `LocalDate` (+1 for that).

Comment: Right, I wouldn't complain if we were talking about `java.util.Date`. But `java.sql.Date` by default represents a date in the default time zone. At least that's how the [JDBC treats it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-).

Comment: Good to know.  Thanks.

Comment: As I read the docs, years up to and including 9999 are supported by the outdated `java.sql.Date` class. In its interface 9999 is represented as 8099 since its years are 1900-based.

Answer (score 3):

Use Java's new `LocalDate` class. If you must have a `java.sql.Date`, you can convert it with `valueOf()`:

```
Date eot = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(9999, Month.DECEMBER, 31));
```

Answer (score 1):

@shmosel's answer is not in UTC. Also `valueOf` is really, really slow.

`Constants` is 7 nanos `ValueOf` is 430 per operation:

```
Benchmark                  Mode  Cnt    Score     Error  Units
DataTimeUtilsJmh.constants avgt    5    6.929 ±   3.166  ns/op
DataTimeUtilsJmh.valueOf    avgt    5  429.592 ± 211.741  ns/op




public static final LocalDate MAX_ORACLE_DATE_AS_LOCAL_DATE = LocalDate.of(9999, Month.DECEMBER, Month.DECEMBER,Month.DECEMBER.maxLength());

public static final LocalDateTime START_OF_DAY_ON_MAX_ORACLE_DATE_AS_LOCAL_DATE_TIME = MAX_ORACLE_DATE_AS_LOCAL_DATE
    .atStartOfDay();

public static final Instant UTC_START_OF_DAY_ON_MAX_ORACLE_DATE_AS_INSTANT = START_OF_DAY_ON_MAX_ORACLE_DATE_AS_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
    .toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

public static final long UTC_START_OF_DAY_ON_MAX_ORACLE_DATE_AS_EPOC_MILLIS = UTC_START_OF_DAY_ON_MAX_ORACLE_DATE_AS_INSTANT
    .toEpochMilli();

@Test
public void test() {

    final java.sql.Date utcStartOfDayMaxOracleDateAsSqlDate = new java.sql.Date(
            UTC_START_OF_DAY_ON_MAX_ORACLE_DATE_AS_EPOC_MILLIS);

    final long time = utcStartOfDayMaxOracleDateAsSqlDate.getTime();

    final Instant ofEpochMilli = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time);

    final OffsetDateTime atOffset = ofEpochMilli.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    final LocalDate actual = atOffset.toLocalDate();

    assertEquals(MAX_ORACLE_DATE_AS_LOCAL_DATE, actual);
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is for a constant and therefore initialized once speed hardly matters (still not having understood the UTC requirement from the question).

Comment: `j.s.Date` should not be a constant as it is mutable. It should ALWAYS be generated. So, yes, performance matters.

Comment: Further the code I supplied, which is derived from code we use for the same purpose, is designed not only for performance but for clarity and accuracy as well.  We use the constructs the standard library provides (`Month.December`, `Month.DECEMBER.maxLength()`) and only provide one 4 digit magic number, `9999`, the max Oracle year. The constant, `253402214400000L`, is derived from these well understood domain specific values.  It is important to remember that code of any significance is read more than it is written.